# Disable Huawei Swiftkey in UI tests

Tags: android, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

We're running UI tests on Firebase Test Lab. For our release builds, we run a matrix of tests on physical devices, including the Huawei Mate 9. We'd like to keep this in our tests because it's a device that we don't have easy access to locally.

Unfortunately, this type of device appears to have SwiftKey installed by default - and there's a prompt from the system to enable it which pops up in the middle of our test runs. Since this takes us out of our app, it causes our Espresso tests to fail.

So, this leads me to two questions:
1) Is there any workaround for this specific device? Anything we can do to turn off or suppress SwiftKey during tests?
2) Are there any general tips on how to deal with this kind of failure during UI tests? I assume there's no silver bullet - but any advice on best practices would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Firebase Test Lab as of Feb 1, 2018.